# dropdownlist hierachy of options filter

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a hierarchy of many records (a 1000 to be exact) that I display in a dropdownlist. Is there a way to filter this list down with a keyup event of the select/option list?

```
<select id="food">
  <option>Foods</option>
  <option>&nbsp; Fruits</option>
  <option>&nbsp;&nbsp; Apple</option>
  <option>&nbsp; Vegetables</option>
  <option>&nbsp;&nbsp; Carrot </option>
</select>
```

Thanks,
rod.

Comment: Sidenote: you might want to use <optgroup> instead of &nbsp;: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use something like a jQuery Autocomplete plugin:

http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm